# Calculating time difference Python

Tags: python, datetime, math, difference

I'm trying to calculate the difference in hours and minutes between two 24hr format times.
I can't seem to find or get my code to work for two times with the same hour value eg 13:32 and 13:36, it works fine when calculating times with different hr values. If possible I don't want to use the date.time module and can assume 2nd time is later than 1st.

```
time1hr= 13
time1min= 32
time2hr= 13
time2min= 36

min_diff= 60 - time1min + time2min
hour_diff= abs(time2hr - time1hr) -1
```

Comment: Why don't you want to use the `datetime` module?

Comment: @hjpotter92 sorry meant to be time2min

Comment: @abarnert We have to try and do it with using the datetime module

Comment: make sure you read "Falsehoods programmers believe about time" http://infiniteundo.com/post/25326999628/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-time and http://infiniteundo.com/post/25509354022/more-falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-time-wisdom

Comment: @bgbg: Nice link. I can't tell you how many programs I had to debug because they tried to, e.g., apply the 2007-and-later US DST rules to pre-2007 dates. If I were dictator of the planet, everyone would just reckon time in GMT, and if that means you have to get to work at 23:00 and go home at 08:00, well, that's fine, because midnight happens at 14:00 where you live, so 23:00 is a perfectly reasonable time to get to work…

Comment: @abarnert there was a similar attempt: Swatch Internet Time (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swatch_Internet_Time) -- unfortunately it wasn't adopted

Comment: @bgbg: Yes, but Swatch time tried to get rid of the base-24/60 time in favor of decimal days, and went with bizarre non-SI nomenclature for their decimal days to boot, and wasn't consistent with what a day meant (they claimed it was a mean solar day, but then tried to define it in terms of an atomic clock on a satellite which obviously doesn't count in terms of solar days). If you were intentionally designing a system with the goal of making time reform seem stupid, you couldn't do much better.

Comment: @bgbg: Also, the Swatch marketing department forgot the vital step of making me dictator of the planet. Hopefully the next people who try to reform the time system will remember that step.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you can't calculate a difference by adding, but that's exactly what you're trying to do here:

```
min_diff= 60 - time1min + time2min
```

Also, if you can assume that time2 is later than time2, why are you using `abs` here?

```
hour_diff= abs(time2hr - time1hr) -1
```

Finally, you're adding 60 to `min_diff` and subtracting 1 from `hour_diff`. That's obviously the right thing to do if `min_diff` overflows to negative. But that will only happen if `time1min` is larger than `time2min`, not every time. (And only if you subtract instead of adding, of course.) You do need to handle this—just because you can assume the second time is later than the first doesn't mean you can assume the second time's minutes are higher than the first's—but you need to handle it only when it happens, otherwise you'll end up with things like "-1 hour, +37 minutes" instead of "-43 minutes".

So, start with this:

```
min_diff = time2min - time1min
hour_diff = time2hr - time1hr
if min_diff < 0:
    min_diff += 60
    hour_diff -= 1
```

If you look at that, you should realize that it's exactly the same way you learned to subtract numbers with 2 or more digits in elementary school, except that you have to carry a 60, not a 10. Think that through and see if you can come up with test cases that might by tricky.

---

What if for some reason you're not allowed to use an `if` statement?

Obviously you can just turn it into a `while` statement; as long as the input values are valid, it will run the "loop" either 0 times or 1 time, for the exact same effect as the `if`, but that's probably cheating. Or you could use ternary if expressions instead of an if statement, but that's probably cheating too.

But a cleverer solution is to use division and remainder to do the carrying. 45/60 is 0 with 45 left over, but -15/60 is -1 with 45 left over.* So:

```
carry, min_diff = divmod(time2min - time1min, 60)
hour_diff = time2hr - time1hr + carry * 60
```

I think this might be overly clever and tricky, but your mileage may vary.

---

<sub>* Not all languages define division and remainder the same way when negative numbers are involved. In Python, division always rounds down, so you get -1 with 45 left over, but in C, division always rounds toward 0, so you get 0 with -15 left over, which wouldn't have helped us at all. Fortunately, we're using Python, not C.</sub>

Comment: Thank you!! The explanation is really helpful. Is there a possible way of doing it without using the if statements?

Comment: @user3903696: On second thought, now that I've written it, it doesn't look too bad. Especially if your teacher was trying to get you to think in terms of base-60 subtraction with carrying, in which case this gets the idea across very clearly. But I'd still prefer the longer and more explicit code if I were reading both.

Comment: Thanks @abarnert! The second method was very helpful, I had to alter it slightly but its working now!

Answer (score 0):

OP is asking, for some obscure reason, for a solution without using `datetime` module and without `if` statements.

One possibility is to convert the times to minutes. Or even to seconds as in my example:

```
def time_diff(t1, t2):
  h1, m1, s1 = t1
  h2, m2, s2 = t2
  s1 = h1 * 3600 + m1 * 60 + s1
  s2 = h2 * 3600 + m2 * 60 + s2
  diff = abs(s2 - s1)
  h_diff = int(diff / 3600)
  m_diff = int((diff % 3600) / 60)
  s_diff = diff % 60
  return (h_diff, m_diff, s_diff)

time1hr = 13
time1min = 32
time2hr = 13
time2min = 36
h_diff, m_diff, _ = time_diff((time1hr, time1min, 0), (time2hr, time2min, 0))
print("Diff in hh:mm is {0:02}:{1:02}.".format(h_diff, m_diff))
# Diff in hh:mm is 00:04.
```

Answer (score 0):

The difference between two datetime objects is a [timelta](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.timedelta) object, which has methods for getting the difference in several ways.

Comment: OK, but how does this help someone who has to subtract times _without using the `datetime` module_, as the problem explicitly says he needs to do?